# A a foreign key child model multiple dynamic forms inside Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, one-to-many

The following is the registered admin models:

**models.py**

```
class TestMain(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    question = models.TextField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    ## If I uncomment below and comment question attr in TestChild it doesnt work
    # answerfk = models.ForeignKey(TestAnswer, related_name="answerfk", on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Question'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Questions'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - QUESTION: {}'.format(self.course, self.question)

class TestChild(models.Model):
    ## If I comment below and uncomment answerfk attr in TestMain it doesnt work
    question = models.ForeignKey(TestMain, related_name="questionfk", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=250, default=None)
    correct_answer = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="correct answer", default=False, editable=True)  
    answer_comment = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=False, default=None)
    internal_comments = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=False, default=None)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{} ANSWER: {} {}'.format(self.question.question, self.answer, self.correct_answer)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class TestMainForm(forms.ModelForm):
  pass

class TestChildForm(forms.ModelForm):
  pass
```

**admin.py**

```
class TestChildInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TestChild
    fk_name = "question"
    extra = 0
    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        TestChildInline.form = type(
            'TestChildInlineAlt', (TestChildForm, ), {})
        formset = super(TestChildInline, self).get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
        return formset

class TestMainAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TestChildInline, ]

admin.site.register(TestMain, TestMainAdmin)
```

The goal is to have a `TestMain` form and a dynamic multiple form addition for `TestChild`. The issue I am facing is if I have the foreign key (models.ForeignKey) in the `TestMain` (`answerfk`) to `TestChild` (`answer` attr) then the inline for `TestChildInline` gives an error saying there is no foreign key in `TestChild` for `TestMain`.

I want to have a fk in TestMain for TestChild how do I create a form for TestMain & TestChild with TestChild being dynamic multi form entry option - inline. I am talking about TestMain->TestChilds with OneToManyRelation. I have a requirement of fetching TestMain with TestChilds for a view/form that needs to enter data for a different model called TestResults. The entry of the TestResults is data from both TestMain+TestChilds form data entering it to TestResults Model.

The form currently has multiple additions for answers like this (`TestChild`[`question` -> (`models.ForeignKey(TestMain)`):

[image]

Comment: I do not understand why you want to change the fk. If you have the fk in your ```TestMain``` only one ```TestChild``` can have a relationship to that main instance so that inlines do not make sense (and are not supported)

Comment: Ok fair enough. If I have have fk in TestMain for TestChild how do I create a form for TestMain & TestChild with TestChild being dynamic multi form entry option - inline. I am talking about TestMain->TesChild with OneToManyRelation. I have a requirement of fetching TestMain with TestChilds for a view that needs to be shown for a different model TestResults entry that is made using this form that has both TestMain+TestChilds